# Отложенная публикация статей

Tags: ajax, php, mysql

Доброго времени суток. Появился еще один вопрос: как можно реализовать отложенную публикацию статьи до минуты + запрет публикации задним числом? В Сети видел варианты, только это плагины для CMS. А я хотел сам узнать с вашей помощью?

Comment: Ну если судить чисто по логике, то вам нужно настроить в js параметр дата таким образом, чтобы нельзя было добавить дату меньше текущей. Это запрет публикации задним числом. Чтобы реализовать отложенную публикацию, настройте в php видимость статей по дате не больше текущей и соотвественно отложенные статьи не будут видны до наступления момента публикации.

Comment: Легко сказать, напиши, про что почитать для отложенной публикации.

Comment: @S6D, комментарий @MasterAlex, потом спросить конкретно те вещи, которые оказались непонятными. Отложенная публикация на уровне CMS именно так и реализуется - ставится дата "вперед", а показываются только те записи, у которых дата публикации <= текущей, в результате записи с забегающей вперед датой просто исключаются из выборки записей для показа.

Comment: Схему, как происходит, это я понимаю в принципе даже легко, но вот именно я не знаю, как сделать выборку по текущей дате. Например, если это выполняется с помощью mysql, то что нужно добавить в обычный запрос выборки, или если php, то какую функцию использовать для этого.

Comment: @S6D просто добавить ``WHERE `publication_date` <= CURTIME()``. На стороне PHP придется итерировать все записи и проверять дату каждой, сравнивая результат функции `strtotime()` с `time()`.

Comment: Спасибо. )) Буду изучать, если что, буду опять обращаться. ))

Comment: Все почитал, лучше скорее всего будет сразу через sql запрос, но не CURTIME() а NOW(). Etki, ты на php пишешь?

Comment: @S6D, да, все правильно, curtime дату не возвращает.

Answer (score 1):

Можно хранить неопубликованые статьи в отдельной таблице,  написать скрипт, который проверяет дату публикации, и если пора,  то переносит в таблицу со всеми статьями,  скрипт запускать на кроне хоть каждую секунду,  этот вариант подойдет, если сайт посещаем и неохота напрягать БД проверкой каждой статьи на время публикации при заходе пользователя.

Comment: в золотую копилку неоправданно дорогих решений.